# How to achieve this using Knockout in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs and mvc-5 in my project. Initially i am using only mvc but now i have decided to add knockout in my project. Now i have stuck in a following situation:

In project i have to give candidates a control from where he/she can add there multiple academic information like:

[image]

Here i am doing this by using partial view. When candidate click on *Add More* button an ajax call get the partial view and insert it in the page like this:

[image]

Now i want to do the same using Knockout. And i want to keep using Html helpers because it will automatically handle the validation which i have inserted using Data-annotations at server side.

I just cant figure out how i can achieve this, can anybody please guide me how i can achieve this??

Thanks.

Comment: Post the HTML/Razor, JS and controller code.

Answer (score 2):

My advice, don't mix worlds. Keep knockout validation in Knockout (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation).

This is very simple to do in [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com), there are many samples on the site under documentation.